# Magento 1.9, Klarna checkout, i can not make an order

Tags: magento-1.9

I can not make an order, writes Sorry, the delivery option you chose cannot be processed.
Here are the delivery settings.
[image]
[image]

Comment: quesiton is about magento 1  or magento 2?

Comment: adout magento  1, sorry

Comment: did you fix it?

Comment: @РомаЛытарь did you found a fix for issue

Answer (score 0):

If you run Klarna Checkout on `localhost`, then you should make the `localhost`-based application reachable from Klarna via the HTTP protocol (e.g., for the [`address_update`](https://developers.klarna.com/api/#checkout-api-callbacks-shipping-option-update) callback).
You can do it via services like [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com).